# Enabling JAX-WS MTOM on JBoss 6 EAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, jboss6.x

I want to enable MTOM. But when i am calling from client i always get NullPointerException.
I am using JAXWS and METRO as its implementation.

Below is my impl class which i exposed as soap.

```
@MTOM
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.poc.control.Controller")
@BindingType(value=javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_MTOM_BINDING) 
public class ControllerImpl implements Controller{

    public String uploadData(Image data){

        if(data != null)
            return "Upload Successfully!!";
        return "check";
    }


}
```

Now from client side below is my code for accessing the above:

```
public class Test {

    private static final String wsUrl = "http://localhost:8080/soappoc/check?wsdl";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MyException{
        URL url = new URL(wsUrl);
        QName qName = new QName("http://impl.control.poc.com/", "ControllerImplService");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qName);
        Controller controller = service.getPort(Controller.class);

        //enable MTOM in client

        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) controller;
        SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();
        binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);

        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\sorabh2169\\Desktop\\photo\\IMG_0003.JPG"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write( originalImage, "png", baos );
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();

        String status = controller.uploadData(imageInByte);
        System.out.println("Status is :: " + status);

    }
}
```

But running the bove code i always get NullPointerException.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at $Proxy28.uploadData(Unknown Source)
    at com.testpoc.Test.main(Test.java:49)
```

If you check the logs you will find that it is saying that *$Proxy28.uploadData(Unknown Source)*
I think this is the problem.

But how to deal this, what went wrong. 
Please advise.

Comment: Can you also add the server logs?

Comment: In server logs there is nothing got printed. Even i put debug point on my soap exposed class, but the call never came there.

Comment: If i remove the @MTOM, then the image is getting uploaded successfully. But i want uploading with MTOM, but that is causing the issue.

Comment: I think, it is something related to the application server i used. Since if i publish my service through a java main program i.e. eith help of  Endpoint.publish(bindingURI, service);  i can successfully upload the file using MTOM.